# UIView's Description Prints Garbage

Tags: xcode, uiview, lldb

I get the following when I do a po on any UIView.

```
(lldb) po [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]
(id) $1 = 0x08731860 + ƒ„*∞Ì*Ä…3    HÜº retain:1 - tag:0 - bgcolor:(r:0 g:0 b:0 a:1.00)
   bounds: x:0 y:0 w:100 h:100 - frame: x:0 y:0 w:100 h:100 - center: x:50, y:50
```

This only happens in one of my projects. Any ideas on what would be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I learned the cause of this issue lives down in the UserVoice static library for iOS.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks for that info. Any clue as to what specifically causes this?